# Bash - Removing files using Arrays

Tags: arrays, bash

I have one flat directory. I have 2 arrays. Array1 stores the contents of the directory (all `.PNG` files). Array2 has six files. These six files are the same as the six files within Array1. How do I use Array2 to remove the 6 files in the directory? Two arrays are as follows:

```
array1= (`ls ${files}*.PNG`)
array2= $(find . ! -name 'PHOTO*')
```

Tried using a `for` loop but not sure how to proceed:

```
for files in $array2;do
    rm -f files $array1
```

Comment: looks like you forgot the `done` command

Comment: Are you trying to delete the files, or remove their names from the array `array1`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. No space is allowed after the `=` in an assignment.
2. Don't parse `ls`. Your code will not work for files whose names contain whitespace.

   ```
   array1=( "${files}"*.png )
   ```
3. Your `array2` isn't an array; it's a string consisting of a sequence of file names separated by whitespace.

   ```
   array2=( $(find . ! -name 'PHOTO*') )
   ```

   Also, using `find` in a command substitution like this can fail for the same reason outlined in 2). Use an extended pattern instead (activated by running `shopt -s extglob`):

   ```
   array2=( !(PHOTO*) )
   ```
4. To iterate over the files in an array, you first need to expand the array into a sequence of words, one element per word:

   ```
   for files in "${array2[@]}"; do
       rm -f "$files"
   done
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To run rm only once... (assuming no spaces in filenames)

```
unset rm_tmpfiles
if [ ${#tmpfiles[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
    for tmpfile in "${tmpfiles[@]}"; do
        rm_tmpfiles+="$tmpfile "
    done
    rm -f $rm_tmpfiles
fi
```